# Using page.evalute() to return DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, testing

In my test script I am trying to access an element on my page like so:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});

const page = await browser.newPage();

(async () => {

    const myElement = await page.evaluate( () => {
        let overflowDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.overflow')[0];
        let buttonDiv = overflowDiv.children[1];
        let listsButton = buttonDiv.children[0]; 
        return listsButton;   
    });

    await page.click(myElement);
...
};
```

When I run this script I get the error `'No node found for selector: undefined'` . I do not understand why myElement in undefined in this case.  Perhaps I do not understand how `page.evaluate()` works?

Comment: Have you debugged it, what's the value of `listsButton`? I bet it's `undefined`

Comment: Inside of the `page.evaluate()` function listsButton is exactly what we expect it to be.  but on `page.click()` it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by me using page.evaluate() instead of page.evaluateHanlde().  One must use page.evaluateHanlde() to create a handle for a DOM node.

The solutions is as follows:

```
(async () => {

    const listsButtonEl = await page.evaluateHandle(() => {
        let overflowDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.overflow')[0];
        let buttonDiv = overflowDiv.children[1];
        let listsButton = buttonDiv.children[0]; 
        return listsButton;   
    });
    await listsButtonEl.click();

}();
```